# python cython ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, cython

This is what i have done, but i failed in `Step3`, I try my best and can't find how to solve it.

step1: install python-2.7.12.amd64 , Cython-0.24-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64 and vs2015.3.com_enu.(there are some problems,but be soveled.)

step2: do as:http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html
       .c and .pyd  files are generated.

step3: but when i import the model, failed with

> "traceback... file'',line 1, in   import...
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

what i should do for this problem? anyone some advances? thanks very much.

Comment: In case of python2.7, [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) is the version that should be used.

Comment: i did, but don't work. thank you all the same, J.J.Hakala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @J.J.Hakala mentioned be sure to use the compiler he linked to or it won't work with your Python version.  Also make sure you have all your includes listed in `setup.py`, i.e.

```
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import Extension

module = 'MyModule'

ext_modules = [Extension(module, sources=[module + ".pyx"],
              include_dirs=['path1','path2'], # put include paths here
              library_dirs=[], # usually need your Windows SDK stuff here 
              language='c++')]

setup(
    name = module,
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = ['path1', 'path2']
)
```

And while building be sure to specify: `python setup.py build_ext --compiler=msvc` in case you have multiple compilers on your system.  While you're at it they note that you need setuptools version >=6.0 so ensure you are up to date there.

Comment: No problem, took many months to learn Cython as the docs / tutorials assume you started out as a pro :)